# pl.pojo.tester.internal.utils.SetterNotFoundException

Tags: spring-boot, java-11, pojo, spring-boot-test, java-17

Trying to upgrade java17/springboot 3.0.6

Using pojo tester version as testImplementation 'com.obsidiandynamics.pojotester:pojotester:0.9.0' .
I assume that 0.9.0 version supports till java 11, is there any latest version or alternate for java 17

This is the error:
pl.pojo.tester.internal.utils.SetterNotFoundException

did not find any latest version of pojo-tester which supports java 17. can anyone suggest